# Exporting GDB tables to Excel in folder containing GDB?

Tags: arcpy, file-geodatabase

I have several folders which each contain a GDB.

Now, I export the attribute tables of polygon feature classes using the following code (probably could use some optimization):

```
folder = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)

for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in arcpy.da.Walk(folder, datatype="FeatureClass",type="Polygon"):
    for filename in filenames:
        fc = os.path.join(dirpath, filename)
        table = dirpath + os.sep + filename + "_Table"
        result = arcpy.GetCount_management(fc)
        if int(result.getOutput(0)) > 0:
            print "Creating " + table
            arcpy.CopyRows_management(fc, table)
```

Output looks like:

```
-folder
--subfolder1
---*.gdb <--contains multiple tables
--subfolder2
---*.gdb <--contains multiple tables
```

I would like to simply output an excel version of the table at the same time, but i am unsure how to parse out the folder containing the .gdb to use as the path for the excel file.

Outout should then look like:

```
-folder
--subfolder1
---*.gdb <--contains multiple tables
---Excel1
---Excel2
---etc.
--subfolder2
---*.gdb <--contains multiple tables
---Excel1
---Excel2
---etc.
```

How would I go about getting that parameter to output the Excel file in the correct location?

Answer (score 2):

[`CopyRows`](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//0017000000n4000000) can't output to Excel, it can only output to dBASE, ArcSDE geodatabase, file geodatabase, personal geodatabase or INFO tables. You need to use the [TableToExcel_conversion](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001200000054000000) tool.

Then you need to use `os.path.dirname` to get the gdb parent directory.

Something like (untested...):

```
import os, arcpy
folder = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)

for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in arcpy.da.Walk(folder, datatype="FeatureClass",type="Polygon"):
    for filename in filenames:
        fc = os.path.join(dirpath, filename)
        xls = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(dirpath), filename + "_Table.xls")
        result = arcpy.GetCount_management(fc)
        if int(result.getOutput(0)) > 0:
            print "Creating " + xls
            result = arcpy.TableToExcel_conversion(fc, xls)
```

Answer (score 1):

Below your 'CopyRows' command, where you're outputting tables inside the gdb, you need to output essentially to a level 'up', as indicated in your diagram...do this with a simple os.path.dirname(dirpath).  (Make sure you've imported the os module.)

FYI, to be consistent you should use os.path.join similarly (instead of '+ os.sep +'):

os.path.join(dirpath, filename + "_Table")

Answer (score 0):

This ended up being really easy after some effort in ModelBuilder.  Just feed it a folder and have your iterator run recursively and it will run thru any number of gdbs in the folder and output excel files for each feature class in each gdb.

[image: ExcelExporter]